# Radiation of an electron in an atom in the Rutherford model

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, acceleration, atomic-physics

In the limitations of Rutherford atom model, it is said that electrons would radiate energy and fall to the nucleus if it rotates in any path other than the allowed circular path.

I want to ask, **how does an accelerating electron radiate energy and how does it not radiate energy in allowed paths? I mean , in a circular path , displacement is perpendicular to force and so work done is zero . Then, how does it lose energy ...?**

[Any conceptual explanation would be helpful.]

Comment: Rutherford's model assumed a circular path. Losing energy due to radiation would mean the path would be a spiral towards the nucleus.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bohr's model of an atom doesn't seem to have overcome the drawback of Rutherford's model](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33743/). See also [Where did Schrödinger solve the radiating problem of Bohr's model?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68381)