# Rutherford's and Bohr's model of atom

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, atomic-physics, atoms, models

Rutherford's model of atom was ruled out because it failed in explaining stability of an atom. Since any particle that is accelerating continuously emit radiation. And in case of an atom eventually electrons fall into the nucleus. Bohr said that they revolve in stable orbits around the nucleus. Still they're in uniform circular motion right? Why don't they radiate energy and fall into the nucleus?

Comment: Bohr said energy levels are quantized in some way. That is there are some discrete levels at witch the electron is allowed and the orbit is stable. The electron cannot be in between two levels. That's how he tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bohr's model of an atom doesn't seem to have overcome the drawback of Rutherford's model](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33743/)